# How to get data after # in URL, using HTML/Javascript?

Tags: html, javascript

**Basic Question Description**: How to get data after # in html?

---

For instance, Wikipedia has "`https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML#Markup`" how would I get the `Markup` attribute from HTML/Javascript?

Answer (score 1):

The name of that value is "anchor". You can get it following way:

```
var hash = location.hash;
```

See the w3c [w3c documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_hash.asp)